# JAWS, ExtJS 6 grid in IE

Tags: extjs, datagrid, grid, extjs6, jaws-screen-reader

I have a problem with ExtJS 6 grids in IE while reading and navigating them with JAWS.

ExtJS 6 grids are basically divs with role="grid" and each row is a `<table role="presentation">` with it's only row with role="row" and the cell with role="gridcell", all rows are grouped in a `<div role="rowgroup">`.

So far so good, this seems to be exactly as examples of merging tables to data grids suggest. 
I've made a simple HTML structure that follows this description and it seems to work in IE.
Yet when I try to navigate with tab and arrow keys in my ExtJS 6 grids JAWS outputs:
- "some content row 0" (no matter which row it is)
- on leaving the table header: "leaving table"

And when I leave form mode with ++ and enter table mode with JAWS key + space and then T, I can only read the current cell via Numpad 5 (which is read again with row 0) and I can't use the arrow keys to navigate the cells, JAWS then only reads "end of row/beginning of row/..." but no content.

Anyone any idea?

Comment: are extjs6 grids like a spreadsheet where you expect a keyboard user to be able to use simple arrow keys or tab to navigate through the cells?  and each cell can be edited?  or is the grid static/non-interactive where it's just showing data in columns and rows?

Comment: Some cells show plain text content, some contain interactive elements. Theoretically users should be able to navigate vith arrow keys and press enter to edit cells. The above described method works fine in Chrome and Firefox.